# Solution for unmanaged buffer assigned to a managed Image

Tags: c#, c++, image, bitmap, c++-cli

I have a char* buffer of a bitmap image that I'm getting from a native DLL.

I'm using C++/CLI to export the native DLL to .Net

I want to create a Drawing.Bitmap object form that buffer without an extra copy.
This can be done with one of the constructors.

The problem is managing the memory, how can I delete the buffer when the Image is collected by the GC ?

I would like to extend Bitmap, keep a pointer to the buffer, and override the destructor.

But, as you know, Bitmap is sealed, and Image can't be inherited....
Any ideas ?

Comment: If your managed interface can expose something else than a Bitmap or Image then you could create a **disposable wrapper** and forward some methods to the Bitmap, or directly expose the underlying Bitmap through a property.

Comment: @Pragmateek The problem with exposing an underlying Bitmap is that it will hold a different reference counter and may be still used after the containing class is destroyed. I want to keep the containing class alive until noone is using the bitmap anymore

Comment: So you'll have to encapsulate completely the Bitmap. And by using an IDisposable the caller can decide himself of the scope of the Bitmap either using "using" or calling Dispose directly.

Comment: Well, told you so.  A good reason to copy the bitmap pixels instead.

Comment: @Pragmateek That won't work, because a user can still get a reference to the bitmap, and do stuff with it (show it in form for example) but the class that originally held the bitmap (and the unmanaged array) will be already destroyed

Comment: @HansPassant yes you did :) But that would be expensive.

Comment: @YochaiTimmer: of course if the user needs the genuine Image/Bitmap classes... :(

Comment: Your native DLL or someone else's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congratulations, you've run into a prime example of why it's strongly recommended for DLLs to fill in a caller-supplied buffer instead of returning a pointer to memory allocated within the DLL.  By using a caller-supplied buffer, you allow the caller to manage its lifetime using whatever method he likes.  C++ callers can use smart pointers.  .NET callers can use garbage collection.  Buffers associated with images can be owned by the Bitmap instance.

In your case, the best solution is to create the Bitmap of the appropriate size and pixel format, call `LockBits` to get access to its internal buffer, and pass a pointer to that buffer to the DLL which can then place its output directly into the bitmap.  Finally, call `UnlockBits`.